# How to parse a dynamic JSON schema in Talend

Tags: json, talend

I have a Rest API that returns a JSON, but the same field is sometimes returned as an object and sometimes as an array based on available data, I'm using tExtractJsonFields component and it can't handle this change in the schema, let's take the "stage_is" field for example: for one call the API returns this :

{
"stage_id":[
1,
"New"
]
}

to get the ID it should be parsed this way stage_id[0]

for another call I would get this :

{
"stage_id":1
}

and now it is parsed like this : stage_id

[image]

is there any known ways to handle this ? I'm trying to look for  the simplest solution possible before jumping into using something like the tSystem component and use an external tool or a bash script to solve this, thank you guys for your help in advance.

Comment: incorrect JSON in example:
{"Name" : "Value"}
but: {[ "stage_id":[ 1, "New" ] }] - ???

Comment: @PowerMouse thank you sir, I think I have corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Talend doesn't handle dynamic json or at least I am not aware of any solution using native components.
I suggest you modify your json before parsing it, so that stage_id is always an array, that way you can parse it with `stage_id[0]`, like so:
[image]

By placing a tReplace component before tExtractJSONFields, and using this regex

```
(\"stage_id\"\\s*:\\s*)(\\d+)
```

And as a remplacement string: `$1\\[$2\\]`

This will search for occurences of stage_id followed by a number, and surround that number with brackets.
So, `{ "stage_id":1 }` becomes `{ "stage_id":[1] }`
If you get `{ "stage_id":[1, "New"] }` it will not match the regex and won't be modified.

tExtractJSONFields with `stage_id[0]` will then parse it in both cases.

Comment: Please consider accepting this as the correct answer if it solved it for you:)

Comment: I just did, sorry I'm new to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

since you have a broken example just giving you an idea.

```
void Main()
{
    //array
    var j = "{\"stage_id\":[{\"id\":1,\"val\":\"New\"}]}";
    Test res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(j).Dump();
    //one rec
    j = "{\"stage_id\": 1 }";
    res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(j).Dump();
}

public class Test
{
    public object stage_id {get;set;}
}
```

[image]

Comment: if you want to differentiate between results add function:
public bool IsList(object o)
{
 if (o == null) return false;
 return o is JArray;
}
use : IsList(res) - will return true/false so you will know how to handle result

Comment: The OP is asking for Talend solution, this does not answer the question.